# Probabilities of Survival

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

So I have these estimation of survival probabilities for men:

The probability that a man lives at least $70$ years is $80\%$.

The probability that a man lives at least $80$ years is $60\%$.

The probability that a $80$ years old man lives at least $90$ years is $40\%$.

The first question was what is the probability that a man lives at least $80$ if he has just celebrated his $70^{th}$ birthday?

---

**What I did** : I let $A$ be a man who reached $70$, and let $B$ be a man who reached $80$

$$P(A)=0.80$$
$$P(B)=0.60$$

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}=\frac{0.60}{0.80}=0.75$$

> My question is what is the probability that this man lives at least
>   $90$ years?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your notation, let $C$ be the unconditional probability of living to $90$ years.  Then you are given $$\Pr[C \mid B] = 0.4,$$ that is to say, given that a man has lived to $80$ years, the probability of living to $90$ is $0.4$.  Then what you want to find is $$\Pr[C \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[C \cap A]}{\Pr[A]} = \frac{\Pr[C]}{\Pr[A]}.$$  But $$\Pr[C \mid B] = \frac{\Pr[C \cap B]}{\Pr[B]} = \frac{\Pr[C]}{\Pr[B]},$$ so $$\Pr[C] = \Pr[C \mid B]\Pr[B]$$ and $$\Pr[C \mid A] = \frac{\Pr[C]}{\Pr[A]} = \frac{\Pr[C \mid B]\Pr[B]}{\Pr[A]}.$$  Now you can substitute all the values you have to get the answer.